# Nullable compound primary key

Tags: sql, database, oracle, constraints, unique-constraint

I want to be able to do the following:

```
insert into myTable values ('myParamName', NULL, 'alskdjflas');
insert into myTable values ('myParamName', 'A', 'asdf');
```

BUT it needs to give an error when I run this after:

```
insert into myTable values ('myParamName', 'A', 'asdf2');
```

I also need to be able to do this:

```
select * 
from parameters p 
left join myTable mt on mt.parameter_id = p.parameter_id 
                     and mt.visible_mask_substring = NULL
```

And this:

```
select * 
from parameters p 
left join myTable mt on mt.parameter_id = p.parameter_id 
                     and mt.visible_mask_substring = 'A'
```

So I need to be able to `LEFT JOIN` on the second column, but this cannot be done without making the second column a primary key, but it can't be a primary key because primary keys can't be null, but my data needs to have an optionally null 2nd column.

I am about a minute away from giving up and just inserting the word "NULL" in quotes simply so I can have the second column be a PK but allow it to be nulled (**likely not a proper solution**):

```
 DROP TABLE myTable;

 CREATE TABLE myTable 
 (
    parameter_id varchar2(40),
    visible_mask_substring varchar2(1),
    someVal varchar2(50),

    PRIMARY KEY (parameter_id, visible_mask_substring),
    CONSTRAINT idek_ibfk_1 
        FOREIGN KEY (parameter_id) REFERENCES parameters (parameter_id)
 );

 insert into myTable values ('myParamName', 'NULL', 'alskdjflas');
 insert into myTable values ('myParamName', 'A', 'asdf');
```

Comment: You can join on columns without keys. It's just slower.

Comment: You could use a nullable unique key constraint instead of a primary key constraint. Also, you can LEFT JOIN on nullable columns.

Comment: On a side note: It's `and mt.visible_mask_substring IS NULL`, not `and mt.visible_mask_substring = NULL`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Sorry, was HQL syntax originally but tried to replace most of it with normal sql syntax... guess I missed that

Answer (score 1):

A primary key is after all just a unique constraint on certain not nullable columns in the table. You want a unique key on the columns `parameter_id` and `visible_mask_substring`. But unlike is common in SQL, you want to treat NULL in `visible_mask_substring` as if it were just another particular value.

As `visible_mask_substring` can contain any possible string, it is technically not possible to have a unique index on just these two columns and treating NULL as an additional value.

There are two solutions, both using function indexes:

If you know a value that will never ever be used, use that to represent NULL. E.g. the string '###NULL###'. The index would look like

```
create index idx on mytable 
(
  parameter_id,
  nvl(visible_mask_substring, '###NULL###')
);
```

If you cannot guarantee that any value will never be used (or if you just want a clear universal solution), use three columns:

```
create unique index idx on mytable 
(
  parameter_id,
  nvl(visible_mask_substring, 'NULL'),
  decode(visible_mask_substring, null, 'NULL', 'NOTNULL')
);
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/8HwR8Hox

Comment: Which column(s) would be the primary key(s) then?

Comment: Oh nevermind I see, the pks would be the same.. so either way would still need 'NULL' to be text, not a literal null sadly...

Comment: Wait but then this means I need to make the field be varchar(4) instead of varchar(1) which shouldn't be allowed because it needs to be only 1 character long or be null???

Comment: No, you got it wrong. First thing is it's a real NULL. Haven't you looked into the demo? As to the primary key: The table has no official primary key, because there are no non-null columns that uniquely identify a row, and this is how a primary key is defined. But you have an unofficial primary key, as the constraint makes sure that NULL is treated just like another value. That makes parameter_id + visible_mask_substring the primary key, only not according to the official definition.

Comment: And no, you don't have to make the column `VARCHAR2(4)`, as it only holds single characters and NULL. `VARCHAR2(1)` is appropriate and sufficient.